# CSS: overflow-y:auto or overflow-y:scroll hides pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some dynamic info and it has a pseudo element that looks like an arrow,

HTML :

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    something
  </div>
</div>
```

`#inner` div will have some dynamic list of info.
CSS for `#outer` div:

```
#outer{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:grey;
}
```

CSS for the `#inner` div :

```
    width: 30%;
  margin-left:15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float:left;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-left:50px;
  position:relative;
```

CSS for the pseudo element:

```
content: " ";
position: absolute;
left: -25px;
top: 50px ;
border-top: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid #FFFFFF;
border-left: none;
border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
```

On adding an `overflow-y:auto` or `overflow-y:scroll` to the `#inner` div the psuedo element gets hidden.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o3g0p1dx/3/

How can I overcome this?
I need to have both the pseudo element visible and the scroll bar on the div.

Comment: Share also your HTML. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek,thank you for your response.Its a React project with pretty huge html,this particlar div is deeply nested.
Not sure how I can post it all here

Comment: Well, according to StackOverflow rules any question needs to be [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you are not able to post question sticking to MCV rules it's off StackOverflow. We can't help you without HTML and working example, even if we'd like to.

Comment: @AndrzejZiółek I have updated the question accordingly.
Please have a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no HTML/CSS expert, but how about just adding one wrapper and add the arrow to the #wrapper and scrollbar to the #inner element?

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner">
    something
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

#outer{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:grey;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 30%;
  margin-left:15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float:left;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-left:50px;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:visible
}

#inner{
  height:calc(100% - 20px);
  width:calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow-y:scroll;
  padding:10px;
}

#wrapper::after{
  content: " ";
position: absolute;
left: -25px;
top: 50px ;
border-top: 25px solid transparent;
border-right: 25px solid #FFFFFF;
border-left: none;
border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/o3g0p1dx/21/

Comment: Hmm,that seems to be the solution for now.Thanks.
But do you have an idea why it is not being possible to have both a scrollbar and a pseudo element on the same div?

Comment: It is possible to have them, however the pseudo element is not gonna be visible outside of the parent div if the parent has overflow other than visible. what overflow hidden/scroll does, is that it hides all content that is not inside the div itself, I do not think it is possible to overcome this without some kind of wrapper. If the pseudo element was inside the parent div, all would be fine with any kind of overflow since, it is not overflowing

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code snippet and see if this achieves your purpose or not.

```css
#outer{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:grey;
}

#inner{
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float:left;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-left:50px;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:calc(100vh - 40px);
}

.test {
 height:calc(100vh - 40px);
 overflow:auto;
 position:relative;
}

#test::after{
 content: " ";
 position: absolute;
 left: 25px;
 top: 50px ;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-right: 25px solid #FFFFFF;
 border-left: none;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
 <div id="test" class="test">
  <div id="inner">
   something
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe below approach solves your issue. I added `#inner-content` element with `overflow-y: scroll`, so to make content scrollable.

```css
#outer {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: grey;
}

#inner {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: left;
  height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#inner::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: 50px;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  border-right: 25px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

#inner-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="inner-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```